# Tomcat 8.5 - Error 403 Forbidden or empty params on POST request

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration

My web application consists of a html page which submits data to a java servlet that generates a pdf file from it.
On local testing and the test server everything worked fine, but since I use the production server, which is mapped to a registered subdomain together with a certificate and use of https, I got error `403 - Forbidden You don't have permission to access /Project/servlet on this server`. The html will be included in a different website on a different machine than the tomcat server.

**How could I allow access to the servlet?**

Edit:
I tried to submit the form via JavaScript, this gives me no 403 error but status code 200, but sends an empty request body - with no parameters which is pretty useless.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = serverpath + "/servlet";
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        window.open(xhr.response);
    }
}

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    value1: "1",
    value2: "2",
    value3: "3"
 }));
```

When using `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');` instead and sending in form of `xhr.send('value1='1'&value2='2'+'&value3='3');` it's back on error 403 Forbidden.

Here is my web.xml of the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>StaticsCalculator</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>html/htmlpage.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>servlet</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>logging.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me also. For post request, My request was like this:

`{
      url:url,
      method: 'POST',
     dataType : 'json',
   }`

It was throwing 403 error in one of the Tomcat instance.

After adding data and contentType, it started working properly.

`{
      url:url,
      method: 'POST',
      contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      dataType : 'json',
      data:'',
   }`

My url contains the query parameters. What I believe, The 403 forbidden coming in this case is related to tomcat configuration because for me it was working in my local but was having issue on some other tomcat instance.